# Is IP routing table required for host to host communication

Tags: networking

Only two hosts are available with IP addresses

192.168.1.2

and

192.168.1.3

What will be the routing table entries, if one has to setup?
What will be the Next Hop if only one interface is there on each machine.

Data can be transferred to and from both the machines.

Basically, my doubt is what will be the next hop in each case

1. If the packet has to be delivered to some other network (then i think it will be the IP address of the router connecting to it)
2. If the packet has to be delivered locally (same subnet) what should be the next hop IP
3. If the packet has arrived on the host, and it has to be given to upper layers (since it has to see once the routing table, what will be the entries in this case)

All entries in the routing table are static.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have the standard network mask of `255.255.255.0` for those IP addresses, then no you don't need a routing table, or a default gateway since both machines are in the same network.

A routing table is basically a set of directions for how to get to another network. It says that if you want to go to `12.34.56.78` then go out of x network card, and to go `192.168.1.x` (presuming you are on the `192.168.1.0` network)

A default network basically says if you're not on this network, and there's not a more precise route i.e. `12.34.56.78` above. then just go through a particular network address.

A local network works through broadcasting, machine A will send a broadcast packet to MAC (hardward) address `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` which will be accepted by all traffic on the network. (that isn't separated by a router). The broadcast packet basically says 'who owns IP Address x.x.x.x'

When the machine that owns that address receives that packet it sends a reply back saying 'I do'

Machine A can then start sending packets directly to MAC address of that machine, and Machine can reply to the MAC address that sent them.

From this you can understand why routing becomes important, once you start having a large number of hosts on the network, the network can become flooded just from the sheer volume of ARP requests that are bouncing around it. By splitting the address space into separate address blocks you can limit the number of hosts, and number of ARP requests that the network needs to broadcast.

To understand how this works at a lower level, you need to understand how IP addresses and subnet masks are used to determine network membership. Internally an IP Address and network mask are represented as binary numbers. The subnet mask will define the split between the network and the subnet. (it uses a Logical AND obtain the network id)

```
Address:        11000000 10101000 00000010 00000010
Subnet Mask:    11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

Once it has the network id it can compare that to the address it is trying to send (using the same logic) to and determine what to do with it.

The logic for that goes something like this

If a packet's Network id matches a local network id send it directly, without routing.

If a packet's network id matches a specific route in a routing table. for instance if the packet is 10.1.1.1, and there is a route for 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0 then forward the packet to the route marked in that routing entry.

If a packet's network id doesn't match a specific route, and there is a default gateway specified, then forward it there.

If there is no specific route, and no default gateway, return a failed send.

P.S. this is very simplified, in reality there are additional nuances!

Comment: Thanks, how the entries will differ, if the host has to transmit/receive data in the same subnet. What will be the next hop in this case

Comment: if both machines are in the same subnet, there is no hop involved, before sending a packet the machine will check whether it is in the same subnet, if it is it will use ARP to send the packet to the destination, if it isn't it will use ARP to find the address of the next hop and forward the packet there instead.

Comment: Thanks Michael, got it !!

Comment: What if A had multiple interfaces, how would A know which interface to send the frame through? Wouldn't that require using the routing table?